# Read a CSV file and make HTTP POST to API URL from each line in python?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a csv file and I want to POST it to an Django REST API URL.

I can post but It's only the last row from the csv file

This is my code

```
import requests
import os
import csv

def insert_data_to_api():
    # CSV file path
    csv_folder = "csv"
    csv_file_name = "my_data.csv"
    csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_folder, csv_file_name)
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/url/"

    with open(csv_file_path, newline='') as file:

        # create a CSV reader object using DictReader
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)

        print("")
        print("==== FOR LOOP =====")
        print("")

        # iterate over each row in the CSV file
        for row in reader:
            # access the values in the row using the column headers
           
            print(row)

        print("")
        print("==== From data =====")
        print("")

        response = requests.post(url, json=row)

        if response.status_code == 200 or 201:
            print("Data inserted successfully")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to insert data: {response.status_code}")

insert_data_to_api()
```

That's the code that i used. tried to insert all but it insert only the last data from .csv file.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what you mean with `I can post but It's only 1 for example (1 User) and when I use a .csv file...`

Comment: you have no loop around requests.post()...  and please print(row) before the requests.post to see the content

Comment: you want to send data as dict to the api , so better use csv.DictReader

Comment: How sir to do that sir ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read csv to dict sample from
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

this is the rough outline in your case:

```
rows = []
    with open(read, 'r') as file:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(file)
        
        for row in csvreader:
            rows.append(row)
    
    print(rows)
    print("")
    print("==== Sending POST to an API URL ===")
    print("")
    
    for row in rows:
        response = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(row))
        print(response)
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert the row from for loop inside the data = {} ?

Comment: I tried to use the row but it insert only the last data from my csv file.

Comment: see uodated answer

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to create a dict and put this into your working function.
(You could also do this with the `pandas` module).

creating a dict is done like this:

```py
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    data = {}

    for row in reader:
        data[row['region']] = row
```

Now you are able to read parse the dict into your function `insert_data_to_api()` although you will need to modify it to take a dict as an argument.